# remove colon and - between numbers

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a file like this:

```
chr1:34610-36081          1.20286
chr1:69090-70008          0.0392553
chr1:321083-321115        0
chr1:321145-321207        85.0555
chr1:367658-368597        0.114414
```

And I want to convert in to:

```
chr1 34610 36081          1.20286
chr1 69090 70008          0.0392553
chr1 321083 321115        0
chr1 321145 321207        85.0555
chr1 367658 368597        0.114414
```

I can remove the colon but I cant create a space between them

```
cut -d: -f1,2 file | sed s/\:/\/g
```

Comment: sed s/\:/ /g doesn't work?

Comment: no it is giving me like this  chr134610-36081        1.20286
chr169090-70008        0.0392553
chr1321083-321115        0
chr1321145-321207        85.0555
chr1367658-368597        0.114414
chr1420205-421839        0.0936687 i want to create space between them and remove - between location and create space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/[:-]/ /g' file
chr1 34610 36081          1.20286
chr1 69090 70008          0.0392553
chr1 321083 321115        0
chr1 321145 321207        85.0555
chr1 367658 368597        0.114414
```

To store the changes back to the file you can use the `-i` option:

```
$ sed -i 's/[:-]/ /g' file
```

Comment: @user2133307 don't forget to upvote all helpful answers and accept the most useful, you do this by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tr` for this:

```
tr ':-' ' ' < /your/file
```

Answer (score 1):

so far we have `tr` solution and `sed substitution` solution, awk is abit over kill, but we can play it with `sed + tr`: even shorter than `sed s/../../` :)

```
sed 'y/:-/  /' file
```

exampe:

```
kent$  echo "chr1:34610-36081          1.20286
chr1:69090-70008          0.0392553
chr1:321083-321115        0
chr1:321145-321207        85.0555
chr1:367658-368597        0.114414"|sed 'y/:-/  /' 
chr1 34610 36081          1.20286
chr1 69090 70008          0.0392553
chr1 321083 321115        0
chr1 321145 321207        85.0555
chr1 367658 368597        0.114414
```

Comment: so do sed 's/[:-]/ /' file

Comment: @MarkReed this solution is new, isn't it? ^_^